# Java's Collections.sort in Python

Tags: python, class, sorting

I made a class in python and want to do use a function equivalent to Java's Collections.sort() method.
I created a class called elev():

```
def __init__ (self, a):
    self.version = a
    self.length = int(len(a))

def __lt__ (self, other):
    if self.length>other.length:
        short = other.length
    else:
        short = self.length

    for x in range(0, short, 2):
        if not int(self.version[x]) == int(other.version[x]):
            return int(self.version[x]) < int(other.version[x])

        if x==short-1:
            if self.length<other.length:
                return True
            else:
                return False

    return False

def __gt__ (self, other):
    return other.__lt__(self)

def __eq__ (self, other):

    first =  self.__lt__(other)
    second = other.__lt__(self)

    return (not first) and (not second)

def __ne__ (self, other):
    return not self.__eq__(other)`
```

And now I want something like collections.sort(objects) that java has. I created all the 'comparable' - which function do I call to sort my Objects array?

Comment: Are you looking for `sorted`?

Comment: Or just `.sort()`?

Comment: [You were supposed to at least google before posting.](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+sort)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python provides built in support for this:

You can either call `sorted()` around an iterable:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=sorted#sorted

Or call `list.sort()` if your type is a python list:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=list#mutable-sequence-types

Answer (score 0):

In python3,

`list.sort()` modifies the list in-place

`sorted(list)` creates a new sorted list (from an iterable)

For example (in REPL)

```
>>> listA
[0, 1, 2, -1]
>>> sorted(listA)
[-1, 0, 1, 2]
>>> listA
[0, 1, 2, -1]
```

```
>>> listA
[0, 1, 2, -1]
>>> listA.sort()
>>> listA
[-1, 0, 1, 2]
```

In addition,

there is a key parameter to specify a function to be called on each list element prior to making comparisons